# Why was 'Golden' chosen to describe the 'Golden Rule'?

Tags: legalese

Source: *[Introduction to The Study of Law](http://store.thomsonreuters.ca/product-detail/introduction-to-the-study-of-law-8th-edition/)* (8 edn, 2016), p. 99 Middle.

> The golden rule is that the court must reach a conclusion that avoids absurdities.

1. Why 'gold'?
2. What semantic notions underlie 'golden' with its meaning overhead?
   Is the legal Golden Rule related to the [ethical maxim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule)?

Afterword: I posted this [on Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/27853/89), but they judged this a semantic question, not legal.

Comment: Hi Canada. Can you please clarify whether your question is ‘why golden’ or ‘any relation’? The title and body of your question seem to be asking different things.

Comment: Why do we say someone has a heart of gold? Because if they have a heart of tin, it would be worthless. Why do we talk about an era as being golden not iron? Because "gold" is being used metaphorically in "golden rule", it is a  precious metal,  beautiful to look at, resistant and lasting, it does not rust (age) over time, it is in many ways eternal.

Comment: There is (or was?) yet another ["golden rule"](https://books.google.com/books?id=0a4TAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq="golden+rule":+the+rule+of+three.+math), aka the rule of three. It's a pretty old expression in this sense dating back to 1543.

Comment: As Mari-Lou A has already pointed out, gold is used all over the place in expressions meaning definitive, high quality or the best. For example a gold standard (apart from the currency exchange meaning) means the highest standard. Therefore the rule applied in the court is considered to be the highest standard to which a question of law is subjected as a test.

Comment: Why is the most important medal in an Olympic competition the "gold medal"?

Comment: @Canada Yes, certainly - but you should make one of them your main question and the other a related detail.

Comment: @Lawrence Done.  Better?

Comment: Cite the introductory sentence from Wikipedia, *“The Golden Rule (which can be considered a law of reciprocity in some religions) is the principle of treating others as one would wish to be treated. It is a maxim that is found in many religions and cultures”* Why do you expect users to click on links in order to understand what you're talking about?

Comment: @Canada Better, +1 :) . I've edited #1 to make it more direct. Please feel free to roll it back if you prefer the other wording.

Comment: @Lawrence wouldn't "golden" have been better? It's not a “gold rule” but a *golden* one. Now, *that* would make a good on topic question....

Comment: @Mari-LouA I gathered that the question was about the reference to the metal (eg why not the platinum rule or some such), rather than the part of speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article on the Golden Rule to which your question links, the golden rule of "doing unto others as you would have them do unto you" exists in virtually all major religions and was first explicitly published around 1600.

Silver and gold have been for centuries the two monetary standards and, to summarize briefly, the main component (one or the other) of available coins.  The qualities of gold over other metals--its divisibility, measurability (by weight), durability, and the like have made it idea for transactions and the store of value.  The difficulties of gold as the monetary standard came to the fore politically with William Jennings Bryant's "Cross of Gold" speech. Changes were made in the 1930s in the U.S., when paper money was substituted and citizen-owned gold was called in, and in the !970s, when the U.S. went off the gold Standard for its money because it didn't want to ship to Great Britain the payments that country was demanding.  This ended the era of fixed exchange rates tied to gold.

Informally phrases such as "the gold standard is taking out the garbage every day" have come to be used, along with the cynical crack, "He who has the gold makes the rule."

It is also used metaphorically in many other areas as a golden rule or a golden standard. In recent decades, credit card companies have tried to promote a platinum (or black) card as better than a gold card. (None of them was actually made of metal).  So as @Mary Lou A pointed out in a comment, gold is the prized standard among metals for its various features and therefore applied to many areas as a "best" standard or practice.

If you use Google NGrams to explore various uses, golden *,rule * with the box checked to ignore capitalization (the term is often capitalized) is best, followed by reading a selection of actual texts from different eras.

Comment: One should take care not to conflate *gold* and *golden*. The gold standard is no longer the golden standard, and the golden rule has never been the gold rule.